# Git checkout sometimes merges, sometimes warns

Tags: git

I'm not sure what I'm doing differently,

My desired behaviour is:

```
$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    test.py
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

But, in other repositories, I get:

```
$ git checkout master
M   test.py
Switched to branch 'master'
```

I've checked the two .config files, but can't see any difference.

Comment: The `M` doesn't actually mean "merged", it means "this file is modified".  The short version is, `git checkout other-branch` will leave modified work-tree files modified, and switch to the other branch, if and only if it's "safe" to do that, i.e., there's no need to touch the file in the process of changing branches.  The idea here is that you probably modified it first, and only *then* realized: "oh wait I wanted to do that on other-branch".  So it lets you switch, unless switching to other-branch requires that *git* change the file too.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case the `master` branch contains changes to `test.py` since you started working in your other branch:

```
feature (*)       D--E--F
                 /
master       A--B--C
```

Checking out `master` (at revision `C`) conflicts with your working copy changes.

In the second case, `master` contains no changes to `test.py` since you started working:

```
feature (*)      D--E--F
                /
master      A--B
```

Checking out `master` (at revision `B`) does not conflict with your working copy changes. `D`, `E` and `F` did not modify `test.py`.